# Drag and Drop on Canvas using robot framework

Tags: canvas, robotframework, drag, drop

I need to perfrom Drag and Drop on Canvas using Robot framework and I am unable to do so.

It drags the object but doesnt perform a drop option. Tried many things like modify javascript, drag and drop by offset, drag and drop with intermidiate position with mouse down and mouse up.

Here is the snippet

[image]

Java script file

```html
var dataTransfer={
                    dropEffect:'',
                    effectAllowed:'all',
                    files:[],
                    items:{},
                    types:[],
                    setData:function(format,data)
                    {
                        this.items[format]=data;
                        this.types.append(format);
                    },
                    getData:function(format)
                    {
                        return this.items[format];
                    },
                    clearData:function(format){}
                };
var emit=function(event,target)
                {

                    var evt=document.createEvent('Event');
                    evt.initEvent(event,true,false);
                    evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;
                    target.dispatchEvent(evt);

                };

function getElementByXpath(path) {
    return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

var DragNDrop=function(src,tgt) {
    src = getElementByXpath(src);
    tgt = getElementByXpath(tgt);
    emit('dragstart',src);
    emit('dragenter',tgt);
    emit('dragover',tgt);
    emit('drop',tgt);
    emit('dragend',src);
    return true;
}
```

Could you please assist.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Drag And Drop` or `Drag And Drop By Offset` keyword :

Documentation : https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Drag%20And%20Drop

Comment: Hi !! I am aware of drag and drop by offset but that doesn't work. Hence I am posting here. I have shared Java script and the tag. What's happening is , it's dragging but not dropping and the script result is shown as pass. Has anyone here tried drag and drop on canvas. Please help